# Como fazer update via ajax + php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

Quero fazer update de dados através de um modal, no entanto não está atualizando. Alguém tem ideia do por que não está atualizando?

Modal:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#salvar').click(function() {
        var destino = "<?php echo base_url('protocolo/atualizarprotocolo') ?>";
        var dados= {
            'area': $("#area").val(),
            'status': $('#status').val()
        };
        alert("Protocolo encaminhado com sucesso!");
        location.reload();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: destino,
            data: dados,
     });
      return false;
    });
});
```

```
  <?php
  $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
  if ($id > 0) {
  $querys = $this->protocolo->get_protocol_hist($id)->row();
   ?>
  <fieldset>
  <legend>Encaminhar protocolo</legend>
   <form action="" id="user2">
   <div class="row">
  <div class="small-6 columns">
        <div class="row">
              <div class="small-12 columns">
                    <label for="pt">Protocolo</label>
                    <input type="text" name="protocolo" id="protocolo" disabled="disabled" value="<?php echo $querys->id?>">  
              </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
              <div class="small-12 columns">
              <label for="area">Área</label>
                    <select name="area" id="area">
                    <?php 
                    $array = array();
                    $query = $this->area->get_all_areas()->result();
                    foreach ($query as $area){
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $area->id?>"><?php echo $area->area?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                    </select>    
              </div>
        </div>
  </div>
  <div class="small-6 columns">
        <div class="row">
              <div class="small-12 columns">
                    <label for="numero">Número do documento</label>
                    <input type="text" name="documento" id="documento" disabled="disabled" value="<?php echo $querys->numerodocumento?>">
              </div>
        </div>
  <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
              <label for="status">Status</label>
              <select name="status" id="status">
              <?php 
              $array = array();
              $query = $this->situacao->get_all_situacao()->result();
              foreach($query as $linha){
              ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $linha->id ?>"><?php echo $linha->situacao?></option>
              <?php } ?>
              </select>
        </div>
  </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Encaminhar" id="salvar" class="button radius small font encaminhar">
        <input type="hidden" name="idhistorico" value="<?php echo $querys->protocolo_id ;?>">
  </div>
```

Controller:

```
public function atualizarprotocolo(){
    $dados['area_id'] = $this->input->post('area');
    $dados['situacao_id'] = $this->input->post('status');
    $this->protocolo->atualizarhistorico($dados, array('protocolo_id' => $this->input->post('idhistorico')));        
}
```

Model:

```
public function atualizarhistorico($dados = NULL, $condicao = NULL, $redir = TRUE){
      if ($dados != NULL && is_array($condicao)):
         $this->db->update('historicotramitacao', $dados, $condicao);
        if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0):
            set_msg('msgok', 'Alteração efeutada com sucesso!', 'sucesso');
        else:
            set_msg('msgerro', 'Erro ao alterar dados!', 'erro');
        endif;
        if ($redir)
            redirect(current_url()); 
    endif;
}
```

Quando clico no botão, a mensagem de alert é mostrada, no entanto o update não funciona. É exibido a mensagem 'Erro ao alterar dados!.Me parece que é na função model, Mas eu não consigo ver onde tá o erro. Alguém tem ideia?

Answer (score 1):

Olá, não testei, mas percebi que você está fazendo o location.reload() antes de enviar a requisição ajax, tenta fazer as alterações para ver se funciona.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: destino,
    data: dados,
    success: function() {
        alert("Protocolo encaminhado com sucesso!");
        location.reload();
    }
});
```

Comment: Testei, ficou da mesma forma. exibindo a mensagem do model. aparentemente o model está correto, já fiz e refiz esse código diversas vezes e não acho o erro!

Comment: Conseguir resolver o problema. Tinha esquecido de passar o valor do campo hidden(oculto) no ajax, ou seja, o id não estava sendo passado...hehehe!

Comment: Mas que estava estranho dar mensagem de sucesso antes de receber a resposta do servidor, estava.

Comment: Estava, não tinha percebido. Mas o que importa é que foi resolvido!